# Update in USQL Azure Data lake

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

Is there any way by which I can update a value in rowset

**Data:**

```
1,apple,0
2,check,1
3,chec,1
```

**USQL script:**

```
@result = EXTRACT
ID int,
value string,
types int
FROM @"TLD_BT/sacmple.txt"
USING Extractors.Csv();
```

Now I would like to update the above result set @result set type =1 where value is apple

I tried below script.

```
UPDATE @result SET types=1 WHERE value="apple"
```

But I get below error:

```
UPDATE  ### @result SET types=1 WHERE value="apple"

Error
   E_CSC_USER_SYNTAXERROR
Message
    syntax error. Expected one of: STATISTICS
```

Is there anyway by which I can update the value of a rowset or should I find out any other work around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `UPDATE` command in U-SQL at this time but you could use the conditional statement to create a new column and output that.  You could also use the CTAS syntax to create a new internal table.  Examples below:

```
@result =
    EXTRACT [ID] int,
            value string,
            types int
    FROM @"input/input.txt"
    USING Extractors.Csv();

//UPDATE @result SET types=1 WHERE value="apple"
@output =
    SELECT [ID] AS id,
           value,
           value == "apple"? 1 : types AS types
    FROM @result;

// CTAS
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dbo.interimResult
(
    INDEX cdx_Result
    CLUSTERED(id)
    DISTRIBUTED BY
    ROUND ROBIN
)
AS
SELECT [ID] AS id,
       value,
       value == "apple"? 1 : types AS types
FROM @result;


// output result
OUTPUT @output TO "/output/adlaresult.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

Hope that makes sense.  Also see here: [U-SQL DML Statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt621337.aspx)

Comment: Currently ADLA's implementation of U-SQL is an append only store (like most big data stores). Thus as wBob outlines, you have to "recook" the data if you want to make changes or keep track of your "deltas".

Comment: Thanks both of you.

Comment: @wBob I might be wrong. If that's the case, how differential data load is possible. How Azure Data Lake solutions as LET (Load Extract and Transform), are going to used instead of traditional ETL (Extract Transform and Load).

Comment: How can you do this exact same thing but with values from another rowset? So rather then the hardcoded "apple" you could have SELECT value as v from @rowset2 value == v? 1: types AS types

Comment: Hey @Dedawg, sounds like a separate question.  Please post sample data, expected results and what you've tried so far and I'm sure someone will help you.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to update the same table , we create a new partition and insert both Unchanged as well as new records. In this way new partition will always have latest dataset